# how to check collision of tiles and how to add conditions on them using java and libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

```
for(Rectangle tile: tiles) {
    if(koalaRect.overlaps(tile)) {
        // we actually reset the koala y-position here
        // so it is just near the tile we collided with
        // this removes bouncing :)
        if(koala.velocity.y > 0) {
            koala.position.y = tile.y - Koala.HEIGHT;
            // we hit a block jumping upwards, let's destroy it!
            TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(1);
            layer.setCell((int)tile.x, (int)tile.y, null);
        } else {
            koala.position.y = tile.y + tile.height;
            // if we hit the ground, mark us as grounded so we can jump
            koala.grounded = true;
        }
        koala.velocity.y = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

this code is from superkoala.

what i want is when the koala/hero collides with the wall/tile it checks the tile. then i want to change the tile into 3 forms. a solid tile, a slightly cracked tile, a very fragile tile and finally destroy it.

example

```
switch(layer){
"SolidLayer": TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(3);
//get cracked tile
layer.setCell((int)tile.x, (int)tile.y, null);
"CrackLayer": TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(2);
//get fragile tile
layer.setCell((int)tile.x, (int)tile.y, null);
"FragileLayer": TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(1);
//get destroyed layer
layer.setCell((int)tile.x, (int)tile.y, null);}
```

is this possidle?

Answer (score 0):

Create Objects in your editor and use those objects in code using **MapObjects** .

you can get proper bounds from those object and you can use them in your code.

Use this link to solve your queries

https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/GraphicsTileMaps

One important thing

This will help you out only if you are using LibGdx 0.9.9

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the cell to null, set it to the new tile that should occupy that space (if the previous tile was solid, set it to cracked, if it was cracked, set it to null). Then you don't need multiple layers.

Something like this.

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(1);
TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = layer.getCell((int)tile.x, (int)tile.y);
TiledMapTile tile = cell != null ? cell.getTile() : null;
if (tile != null) {
    switch (tile.getId()) {
    case TILE_SOLID:
        cell.setTile(crackedTile);
        break;
    case TILE_CRACKED:
        cell.setTile(null);
        break;
    }
}
```